# django: Where is the annotation happen?

Tags: python, django

I have a very big nested queryset and I get currently this error `annotate() + distinct(fields) is not implemented.` .

**Is there any way to debug which fields have an annotation?**

Are there django functions/internals to find it out?

Comment: You didn't even show us your queryset, we cannot mind debug it for you.

Comment: I don't want mind debug. :) I ask if there a way to find out which fields are annotated! Maybe there are django internals or something to find out what is annotated.

Comment: No what I mean is that you didn't give us enough information to let us help you. If you have a bug you need to show us how did you make it happen. There are so many ways to make an exception happen so we cannot imagine what's yours without at least being about to look at it.